# Adding jQuery to js code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to make this statement using jQuery but cant quite get it to work. In this statement I am clicking on an image in my html and changing it to a new image (img/HeaderImg2.jpg) Please help.

```
  var imageButton = document.getElementById('headerImg');
  imageButton.addEventListener('click', function(e)
  {
   console.log(e);
   imageButton.src ='img/HeaderImg2.jpg';
  } ,false);
```

Comment: Why do you want to switch to jQuery if it's already working with vanilla JavaScript? Don't fix it if it ain't broke.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Perhaps he wants to know more about jQuery.

Comment: I understand that if the javascript works then keep it but I am trying to learn jQuery and how it functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#headerImg').on('click',function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    $(this).attr('src','img/HeaderImg2.jpg');
});
```

Btw, it's better to use vanilla javascript other than using jQuery if you're able to do so.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. If I wanted to make my header change as well when I click the same image how would I do that? right now I am using childnodes.

var pageTitle = document.getElementById('header');
imageButton.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
console.log(header.childNodes);
header.childNodes[1].innerHTML = "Hello"
} ,false);

Comment: You can try to use: `$('#header').find(':eq(1)').html('Hello');`

Comment: _it's better to use vanilla javascript other than using jQuery if you're able to do so_ I'd say that depends, if I already had jQuery library included then I would use it over vanilla JS, but wouldn't include it just for the sake of it. Just be consistent across a project too.